# Add arrow and a side note to a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, luatex

Could anyone know on how to add arrows and side notes to a table like this, I spent 3 days but I'm still struggling with that :( :
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\def\boxit#1{%
  \smash{\color{red}\fboxrule=1pt\relax\fboxsep=2pt\relax%
  \llap{\rlap{\fbox{\vphantom{0}\makebox[#1]{}}}~}}\ignorespaces
}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}

\title{Meow \_ Meow}
\author{user1}
\date{May 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Tabelle 1}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tabular}{ c c|| c g c c c c c c c c c |c c }
 &  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & b/a\\ 
 &  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & \\
\hline\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\rowcolor{Gray} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \textcolor{red}{1}\\ 
\hline
 &  & \boxit{0.1in} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & \\ 
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:table-name}Your caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I only achieved this simple table:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can try the [tikzmark package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark).

Comment: Thank you, i'm also using tikz, Tom's approach worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try to write a command to draw something on document contents. Basically in this command, the second arg #2 is the content that you will put it into a `tikz` node. And first arg #1 is some extra draw using tikz code. In your case the whole `tabular` env will be put into `tikz` node. And you using some `path` commands in the first arg to draw the arrows and notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\def\boxit#1{%
  \smash{\color{red}\fboxrule=1pt\relax\fboxsep=2pt\relax%
  \llap{\rlap{\fbox{\vphantom{0}\makebox[#1]{}}}~}}\ignorespaces
}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}

\title{Meow \_ Meow}
\author{user1}
\date{May 2022}

\newcommand{\addstuff}[2]{\tikz[remember picture]{
\node[inner sep=0pt](current content){#2};
#1
}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Tabelle 1}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\addstuff{
\draw [<-] ([xshift=-2.52cm]current content.north) -- ++(0,1.5) node [anchor=south] {note 1};
\draw [<-] ([yshift=1.5cm]current content.south west) -- ++(-1.5,0) node [anchor=east] {note 2};
}{
\begin{tabular}{ c c|| c g c c c c c c c c c |c c }
 &  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & b/a\\ 
 &  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & \\
\hline\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\rowcolor{Gray} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \textcolor{red}{1}\\ 
\hline
 &  & \boxit{0.1in} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & \\ 
\end{tabular}}
\caption{\label{tab:table-name}Your caption.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked :)